# Combinations of 4 and 3 elements from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I need to split a dictionary of student scores into all possible combinations of groups of 4 and groups of 3.

So far I have

```
from itertools import combinations

student_scores = {"A": 68, "B": 77, "C": 82, "D": 85, "E": 53, "F": 64, "G": 71}
groups_of_4 = list(map(dict, combinations(student_scores.items(), 4)))
```

The trouble comes when I try to get the compliment of these groups of 4. It seems to involve some kind of dictionary difference operator, but my research has not yielded any clarity on how to achieve this - some answers say I need to use sets, others not.

The best I've managed is

```
print(groups_of_4[0], {k: v for k, v in student_scores.items() if k not in groups_of_4[0]})
```

giving a single combination, but I can't see how to modify this to work for all the combinations, especially as the dictionary comprehension only checks for a single item.

Any help solving this much appreciated.

Comment: What is the "compliment" of a group?

Comment: Relative to the whole set, by which I mean the original dictionary, if 4 element are removed, I am informally referring to what remains as the compliment. Is that very confusing?

Comment: No, guess not. I don't think there's any better to do it that what you've already got.

Comment: Why not, `dict.items()` objects support `set` operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the complement using `set` difference operation of `dict.items` objects, and convert them back to `dict`:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations

>>> groups_of_4 = list(map(dict, combinations(student_scores.items(), r=4)))

>>> groups_of_3 = [dict(student_scores.items() - other.items()) for other in groups_of_4]

>>> groups_of_3
[{'G': 71, 'E': 53, 'F': 64},
 {'G': 71, 'F': 64, 'D': 85},
 {'G': 71, 'E': 53, 'D': 85},
 {'E': 53, 'F': 64, 'D': 85},
 {'G': 71, 'F': 64, 'C': 82},
 ...
 {'G': 71, 'B': 77, 'A': 68},
 {'F': 64, 'B': 77, 'A': 68},
 {'E': 53, 'B': 77, 'A': 68},
 {'D': 85, 'B': 77, 'A': 68},
 {'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'A': 68}]
```

You can find more about how `set` properties are implemented in [`dictionary view objects`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) in [`PEP 3106`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but the following (for groups of 4) looks promising:

```
from itertools import combinations

def complement(group, scores):
    diff = scores.keys() - group.keys()
    return {k: scores[k] for k in diff}


student_scores = {"A": 68, "B": 77, "C": 82, "D": 85, "E": 53, "F": 64, "G": 71}
groups_of_4 = list(map(dict, combinations(student_scores.items(), 4)))

for group in groups_of_4:
    print(group, 'complement', complement(group, student_scores))
```

Output:

```
{'A': 68, 'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'D': 85} complement {'E': 53, 'F': 64, 'G': 71}
{'A': 68, 'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'E': 53} complement {'F': 64, 'G': 71, 'D': 85}
{'A': 68, 'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'F': 64} complement {'E': 53, 'G': 71, 'D': 85}
{'A': 68, 'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'G': 71} complement {'E': 53, 'F': 64, 'D': 85}
{'A': 68, 'B': 77, 'D': 85, 'E': 53} complement {'C': 82, 'F': 64, 'G': 71}
{'A': 68, 'B': 77, 'D': 85, 'F': 64} complement {'C': 82, 'E': 53, 'G': 71}
{'A': 68, 'B': 77, 'D': 85, 'G': 71} complement {'C': 82, 'E': 53, 'F': 64}
{'A': 68, 'B': 77, 'E': 53, 'F': 64} complement {'C': 82, 'G': 71, 'D': 85}
{'A': 68, 'B': 77, 'E': 53, 'G': 71} complement {'C': 82, 'F': 64, 'D': 85}
{'A': 68, 'B': 77, 'F': 64, 'G': 71} complement {'C': 82, 'E': 53, 'D': 85}
{'A': 68, 'C': 82, 'D': 85, 'E': 53} complement {'B': 77, 'F': 64, 'G': 71}
{'A': 68, 'C': 82, 'D': 85, 'F': 64} complement {'E': 53, 'B': 77, 'G': 71}
{'A': 68, 'C': 82, 'D': 85, 'G': 71} complement {'E': 53, 'B': 77, 'F': 64}
{'A': 68, 'C': 82, 'E': 53, 'F': 64} complement {'B': 77, 'G': 71, 'D': 85}
{'A': 68, 'C': 82, 'E': 53, 'G': 71} complement {'B': 77, 'F': 64, 'D': 85}
{'A': 68, 'C': 82, 'F': 64, 'G': 71} complement {'E': 53, 'B': 77, 'D': 85}
{'A': 68, 'D': 85, 'E': 53, 'F': 64} complement {'C': 82, 'B': 77, 'G': 71}
{'A': 68, 'D': 85, 'E': 53, 'G': 71} complement {'C': 82, 'B': 77, 'F': 64}
{'A': 68, 'D': 85, 'F': 64, 'G': 71} complement {'C': 82, 'E': 53, 'B': 77}
{'A': 68, 'E': 53, 'F': 64, 'G': 71} complement {'C': 82, 'B': 77, 'D': 85}
{'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'D': 85, 'E': 53} complement {'F': 64, 'G': 71, 'A': 68}
{'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'D': 85, 'F': 64} complement {'E': 53, 'G': 71, 'A': 68}
{'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'D': 85, 'G': 71} complement {'E': 53, 'F': 64, 'A': 68}
{'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'E': 53, 'F': 64} complement {'G': 71, 'D': 85, 'A': 68}
{'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'E': 53, 'G': 71} complement {'F': 64, 'D': 85, 'A': 68}
{'B': 77, 'C': 82, 'F': 64, 'G': 71} complement {'E': 53, 'D': 85, 'A': 68}
{'B': 77, 'D': 85, 'E': 53, 'F': 64} complement {'C': 82, 'G': 71, 'A': 68}
{'B': 77, 'D': 85, 'E': 53, 'G': 71} complement {'C': 82, 'F': 64, 'A': 68}
{'B': 77, 'D': 85, 'F': 64, 'G': 71} complement {'C': 82, 'E': 53, 'A': 68}
{'B': 77, 'E': 53, 'F': 64, 'G': 71} complement {'C': 82, 'D': 85, 'A': 68}
{'C': 82, 'D': 85, 'E': 53, 'F': 64} complement {'B': 77, 'G': 71, 'A': 68}
{'C': 82, 'D': 85, 'E': 53, 'G': 71} complement {'B': 77, 'F': 64, 'A': 68}
{'C': 82, 'D': 85, 'F': 64, 'G': 71} complement {'E': 53, 'B': 77, 'A': 68}
{'C': 82, 'E': 53, 'F': 64, 'G': 71} complement {'B': 77, 'D': 85, 'A': 68}
{'D': 85, 'E': 53, 'F': 64, 'G': 71} complement {'C': 82, 'B': 77, 'A': 68}
```